# How to export Autosys JIL command?

Tags: autosys, jil

I am new to autosys and have to export all the JILs to another server.
Is there a command to export all the JILs at once instead of exporting them one at a time?

Thanks
Abhinav

Comment: This question is about server management software. Unless you are writing software with the autosys SDK, your question should be asked on [sf] instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way to get all the JILs is to use wildcards(%).

```
autorep -J % -q > /tmp/filename.jil
```

Answer (score 3):

Visit this CA DocOps page, got all the necessary info:

https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-ae/11-4-2/en/administrating/ae-configuration/maintain-the-scheduler/back-up-and-restore-definitions

*In short*:

---

```
autorep -M ALL -q > /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your machine definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
autorep -V ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your resource definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory

---

```
autorep  - Y ALL  - q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your user-defined job type definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
autorep -J ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your job definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
monbro -N ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your monitor report definitions are appended to the file that contains your backed-up machine, resource, user-defined job types, and job definitions. A backup of the machine, resource, user-defined job types, jobs, and monitor report definitions is created.

---

```
autorep -G ALL > /directory/globals.txt
```

A backup of the global variable values is created. Your global variable values are saved to a file named globals.txt in the specified directory. This file is a record of what you must redefine after a system failure.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this CA DocOps page, got all the necessary info:

https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-ae/11-4-2/en/administrating/ae-configuration/maintain-the-scheduler/back-up-and-restore-definitions

In short:

---

```
autorep -M ALL -q > /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your machine definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
autorep -V ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your resource definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory

---

```
autorep  - Y ALL  - q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your user-defined job type definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
autorep -J ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your job definitions are saved to a file named autosys.jil in the specified directory.

---

```
monbro -N ALL -q >> /directory/autosys.jil
```

Your monitor report definitions are appended to the file that contains your backed-up machine, resource, user-defined job types, and job definitions. A backup of the machine, resource, user-defined job types, jobs, and monitor report definitions is created.

---

```
autorep -G ALL > /directory/globals.txt
```

A backup of the global variable values is created. Your global variable values are saved to a file named globals.txt in the specified directory. This file is a record of what you must redefine after a system failure.